# Execute code on main IPython thread from within the running kernel

Tags: python, ipython

I would like to queue some code for execution on the main IPython thread from within the running kernel. In other words I want to do something like this (this is pseudocode -- I can't find the APIs to do this).

```
IPython.current_kernel.queue_execution("print 'FOO'")
```

I know I can use `IPython.kernel.connect.get_connection_file()` to get the current kernel's connection info. And then I can construct a client with that connection file. But I would ideally like a way to do this without a connection. Is there a way to do that?

I'm using IPython 2.4.

Comment: I don't think IPython maintains its own queue of requests (ZMQ handles queueing already). Why do you want to queue execution rather than just executing directly?

Comment: Thread affinity issues. I found the solution using ZMQ's IOLoop.

Comment: Also, why the downvote?

Comment: Not me. It's currently showing no votes - perhaps someone accidentally clicked down.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that works for my use case. In my use case, the kernels are created using `IPython.kernel.multikernelmanager.MultiKernelManager` (which runs the kernels out-of-proc). This is different than the kernel running in-process (such as when you just run the IPython console by starting ipython.exe).

So for my out-of-proc kernel case, the following works:

```
zmq.eventloop.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_callback(my_callback)
```

I don't know why exactly it doesn't work for the in-proc kernel case. Perhaps because when you're running the IPython console, the main thread is doing console I/O the whole time (conjecture).